# "Unexpected end of JSON input" while doing mochawesome-merge

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

I tried removing spaces in command as suggested in [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5103#issuecomment-555366159) post. I also tried to reencode mochawesome.json as suggested in [this](https://github.com/Antontelesh/mochawesome-merge/issues/6#issuecomment-627496076) post. But non worked.

You can find my json files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ov47UI3q6zHLypncPjI30czj8nw9HPPb?usp=sharing) on gdrive.

When I try to merge them, I get following error:

```
npx mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/test/test/*.json>cypress/reports/test/test/merged_report.json 
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
ERROR: Failed to merge reports

SyntaxError: cypress/reports/test/test/merged_report.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at F:\myproj-testing\node_modules\mochawesome-merge\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:33:18
    at F:\myproj-testing\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I am on Windows 10. Following are node related version:

```
>node --version
v14.16.0

> npm --version
Debugger attached.
6.14.11
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myproj-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json>cypress/reports/merged_report.json",
    "generate_mochawesome_report": "marge cypress/reports/merged_report.json --reportDir ./ --inline",
    "final_report": "npm run merge && npm run generate_mochawesome_report",
    "generate_report": "python cypress/utils/merge.py && npm run generate_mochawesome_report"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "mochawesome": "^6.2.2",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Update**

I tried running just `mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json` and it printed the merged json on the console. So I tried to first pipe merged json string to `.txt` file, then renaming `.txt` file to `.json` file and finally doing `marge`. Strangely it started working... So these are my updated `package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json>cypress/reports/merged_report.json",
    "mergetotxt":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json > cypress/reports/merged_report.txt",

    "generate_mochawesome_report": "marge cypress/reports/merged_report.json --reportDir ./ --inline",

    "final_report": "npm run merge && npm run generate_mochawesome_report",
    "final_report2": "npm run mergetotxt && rename cypress\\reports\\merged_report.txt merged_report.json && npm run generate_mochawesome_report",

    "generate_report": "python cypress/utils/merge.py && npm run generate_mochawesome_report"
  }
```

Notice following two new scripts:

```
"mergetotxt":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json > cypress/reports/merged_report.txt",
"final_report2": "npm run mergetotxt && rename cypress\\reports\\merged_report.txt merged_report.json && npm run generate_mochawesome_report",
```

Running `npm run final_report2` generates the desired report.

Comment: Please add your `package.json`

Comment: Added package.json

Comment: Can you add space before and after `>`, `"merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json > cypress/reports/merged_report.json",` and then try running `npm run merge`. Run the commands one by one in isolation.

Comment: Well, initially I tried it with spaces only. It didnt work, so I tried it with removing spaces as suggested in [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5103#issuecomment-555366159) post. Also I just tried it once again. No luck. Btw, I tried running just `mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json` and it prints the merged json on the console. So I tried to first pipe merged json string to `.txt` file, then renaming `.txt` file to `.json` file and finally doing `marge`. Strangely it started working... Going to add this to the post

Comment: Although a lot of information here seems not actually relevant to the error: the error is about incomplete JSON, from a specific file: it would be useful to show what the output of `npx mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/test/test/*.json` is on your system _without_ directing it into a file, to make sure it doesn't contain things like helpful stdout console logs like "starting run..." or "merge finished..." etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line :

```
"merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json>cypress/reports/merged_report.json"
```

You cant use an path for the result json.

```
"merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json > merged_report.json"
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

please try this "merge-report":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json > merged_report.txt > merged_report.json",

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
"merge":"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json>cypress/reports/output.json",
"generate_mochawesome_report": "marge cypress/reports/output.json --reportDir ./ --inline",
"final_report": "npm run merge && npm run generate_mochawesome_report"
```

Try it this way, this should work...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Correct command is

```
yarn run mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json -o cypress/reports/report.json
```